# Hardy space, showing the monotonicity of $M(r)=\int_0^{2 \pi}\left|u\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|^p d \theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

This is from lecture notes on the hardy space from NYU [https://math.nyu.edu/~varadhan/harmonic/lecture5.pdf](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/harmonic/lecture5.pdf):

[image]

I was wondering if there is an easier proof that $M(r)$ is monotonically increasing without using the Poisson representation formula which I have never seen before. And what about in the case of p=2 which is even a Hilbert space?

Comment: use the subharmonicity of $|u|^p$; more generally if $g$ subharmonic in $|z|<1$, one has that $m(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{i\theta})d\theta$ is increasing (not necessarily strictly of course) in $0 \le r<1$ and is a convex function of $\log r$

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that when $u(z)$ is an analytic function, then $z\mapsto|u(z)|^p$ is a subharmonic function. Thus you can apply the following:

> Let $g:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a subharmonic function. Then, the function $M(r):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{it})dt$ defined for $r\in[0,1)$ is increasing.

Proof: Let $0\le r_1<r_2<1$. Take $U(z)$ that is harmonic in the disk $\{z: |z|<r_2\}$, continuous on the closed disk $\{z:|z|\le r_2\}$ and $U(\zeta)=g(\zeta)$ for all $\zeta\in\{z:|z|=r_2\}$. Then, by subharmonicity, $g(z)\le U(z)$ for all $z$ in the closed disk $\{z:|z|\le r_2\}$ and therefore
$$2\pi M(r_1)=\int_0^{2\pi}g(r_1e^{it})dt\le\int_0^{2\pi}U(r_1e^{it})dt=2\pi\cdot U(0)=$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi} U(r_2e^{it})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}g(r_2e^{it})dt=2\pi M(r_2)$$
where we used that $U$ is harmonic and Gauss' mean value theorem for harmonic maps.